# File parsing to get specific information

Tags: c#, regex, linq, split, pattern-matching

I have file which looks like this:

```
-- Name John Smith, PhD

[20,00] Title : Software Engineer
[20,00] Employee Id : 20307
[20,00] Level : 41
[20,00] Start Date : 04/21/2014
[20,00] Org : Security
```

Every file contains an entry for just 1 person. I need to extract the name, title and level from this file then create and populate an object of the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Level { get; set; }
}
```

One way to do it is I create a list of strings which need to be matched:

```
List<string> properties = new List<string> { "Name", "Title", "Level" };
```

Then read the file line by line and try to find a match like:

```
properties.Any(x => line.Contains(x))
```

If I find a match, I do some string split and parsing to get the values that I need. But this will involve a lot of manual work. Is there a way I can map the strings to a variable of the class and do this parsing?

What I mean is something like this:

```
Person person = new Person();

Dictionary<string, Object> FieldToDataMember = new Dictionary<string, Object>()
{
    {"Name", person.Name},
    {"Title", person.Title},
    {"Level", person.Level}
};
```

Now I read the file line by line, if it matches one of the keys, I do the parsing and it directly updates the value of the corresponding variable. This way, I don't need to first find whether there's a match and then again check which string it matched to be able to put it in the right variable. Is something like this possible?

Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Edit: I would also like to exit the loop (foreach (string line in file)) and stop reading the file further after I find all the properties I'm looking for.

Comment: You can use reflection to find both the string and the property name from an array of strings, but it won't perform very well. Are you more interested in performance or fewer lines of code?

Comment: Fewer lines as well as cleaner code, but without too much hit to performance. I don't want to end up with lots of if-else loops.

Comment: You have those fields defined as private members. Did you mean to make them public properties instead? Or are they supposed to be private fields?

Comment: I'm sorry, they're supposed to be public. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this using a collection of property name strings is to use reflection to get the property and set the value. This requires extra overhead compared to setting the properties directly, but it is fewer lines of code as you were asking for.

We can use a dictionary or a list of tuples (or a custom class) to map the string in the file with the actual property name (in cases like `"Start Date"` and `StartDate`).

Here's an example where I added a `public static Person FromFile(string filePath)` method, which will take in a file path and return a new `Person` with properties set from the contents of the file.

It works by first determining if any of the property names in the string array are contained in a file line. If one is, then it uses some logic based on your file sample to get the value for that property, and then uses reflection to set the property value of a `Person` object:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }

    private class FileToPropertyMap
    {
        public string FileValue { get; }
        public string PropertyName { get; }
        public bool IsSet { get; set; }

        public FileToPropertyMap(string fileValue, string propertyName)
        {
            FileValue = fileValue;
            PropertyName = propertyName;
        }
    }

    public static Person FromFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath)) throw new FileNotFoundException(nameof(filePath));

        var person = new Person();

        var propertyMap = new List<FileToPropertyMap>
        {
            new FileToPropertyMap("Name", "Name"),
            new FileToPropertyMap("Title", "Title"),
            new FileToPropertyMap("Level", "Level"),
            new FileToPropertyMap("Start Date", "StartDate"),
        };

        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
        {
            // Find a match for one of the properties
            var match = propertyMap.FirstOrDefault(p => line.Contains(p.FileValue));
            if (match == null) continue;

            // Get the value of the property from the file line
            var value = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(match.FileValue) +
                match.FileValue.Length).Trim();
            if (value.Contains(':')) value = value.Split(':')[1].Trim();

            // Set the property value using reflection
            person.GetType().GetProperty(match.PropertyName).SetValue(person, value);

            // Mark this property as "IsSet"
            match.IsSet = true;

            // If we've set all the properties, exit the loop
            if (propertyMap.All(p => p.IsSet)) break;
        }

        return person;
    }
}
```

In use, this would look something like:

```
Person myPerson = Person.FromFile("@c:\Public\PeopleFiles\JohnSmith.txt");
```

Comment: Excellent! This should work. But there might be a small issue. If in the future, I want to add other fields, say Start Date, reflection won't work since the field names won't match. Any way to accommodate that?

Comment: If you want to add properties to the class that have different string representation in the file, like `StartDate` property and `"Start Date"` in the file, then you could create a mapping between the properties using a dictionary as you suggested originally.

Comment: I added an example using a custom class to map the file line value to property name

Comment: Also added an "IsSet" property that can be set for each property value we set, so we can stop reading the file when they're all set.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication167
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            Person person = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("-- Name"))
                    {
                        person = new Person();
                        people.Add(person);
                        person.Name = line.Replace("-- Name", "").Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string pattern = "](?'key'[^:]+):(?'value'.*)";
                        Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
                        string key = match.Groups["key"].Value.Trim();
                        string value = match.Groups["value"].Value.Trim();

                        switch (key)
                        {
                            case "Title" :
                                person.Title = value;
                                break;
                            case "Level":
                                person.Level = value;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Level { get; set; }
    }
}
```